# Blogger redirect to homepage on clicking icon

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I need help with Blogspot theme development. I have created a custom menu for my client. I added home icon on home tab.

But now problem is when I click on home icon, it not going to main page `exp:"mysite.blogspot.com"`. It showing me others link `exp: "mysite.blogspot.com/index.html"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you want to be able to visit your site homepage on clicking your icon. You can achieve it by wrapping your icon with anchor tags:

```
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>$YourIcon$</a>
```

Now, the `$YourIcon$` needs to be replaced by your image/text icon for your site.